# You have requested a non-existent service "security.acl.dbal.connection"

Tags: acl, symfony

when I run init:acl in symfony2.0 
I got this error, anyone knows how to fix it!

```
You have requested a non-existent service "security.acl.dbal.connection"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to enable ACL support in your application. Add this line to your `security.yml` configuration file:

```
acl:
    connection: default
```

Then run `php app/console init:acl` again.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give heads up that, `acl` keywords should be placed on lines following the `security` keyword. If you ONLY put

```
acl:
  connection: default
```

In the top of your `security.yml` file, you may get this error. I am quoting it so that people can come to this thread by googling the error.

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]         
  Cannot import resource "/home/jupiter/symfony/cupon/app/config/secu  
  rity.yml" from "/home/jupiter/symfony/cupon/app/config/config.yml".  
  (There is no extension able to load the configuration for "acl" 
  (in /home/jupiter/symfony/cupon/app/config/security.yml). Looked for   
  namespace "acl", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog",   
  "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "ci  
  udad", "usuario", "tienda", "oferta", "backend", "ideup_simple_pagi  
  nator", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution")    


  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "acl" (in          
  /home/jupiter/symfony/cupon/app/config/security.yml). Looked for na         
  mespace "acl", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "s         
  wiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "ciud         
  ad", "usuario", "tienda", "oferta", "backend", "ideup_simple_pagina         
  tor", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"
```

So just make sure `acl` is after `security` keyword:

```
security:
    acl:
        connection: default
```

Comment: In ArrayNode.php line 331:
                                                                                                                                                                        
  Unrecognized option "acl" under "security". Available options are "access_control", "access_decision_manager", "access_denied_url", "always_authenticate_before_gran  
  ting", "encoders", "erase_credentials", "firewalls", "hide_user_not_found", "providers", "role_hierarchy", "session_fixation_strategy".

Comment: @YusufIbrahim looks like `acl` is not built-in anymore as of Symfony 4.  [Documentation for acl](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html) says: `ACL support was removed in Symfony 4.0. Install the Symfony ACL bundle and refer to its documentation if you want to keep using ACL`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither worked for me. This service is actually not available...

Comment: working or not, if you just update schema using... "php app/console do:sch:upd --force", FW will update you database with ACL tables, and problem solved :)